# Remove https (ssl) from certain url only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove secure http only for a certain url:

```
https://www.example.com/car-sharing.html
```

supposed to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/car-sharing.html
```

I tried several .htaccess directives, for example

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 ^(car-sharing\.html)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} car-sharing.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but I can't get it to work, the redirect from https to http never happens. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How is https redirection handled? What do you mean "can't get it to work"? `%$1` is invalid syntax, though it won't dump an error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The redirect doesn't happen - thats what I meant with I can't get it to work

Comment: BTW Did you turn on rewritengine? `RewriteEngine on` needs to be at the top of your rules.

Comment: @PanamaJack If that weren't the case, wouldn't it cause a 500 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` includes the leading slash, so this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/car-sharing.html
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```